# Is the design of my ADC correct?

Tags: pcb-design, adc

I designed an ADC converter using an ADS1252. The signal comes from a sensor that is split by two using a resistor bridge. The bridge is connected to a voltage follower op amp, its output connected to the ADS1252.

I use a REF5050 for voltage reference and a clock oscillator for sample frequency. The output of the ADC is connected to an arduino using SPI.

I followed as much as possible advice given in each component datasheet.

[image: pcb]
[image: schematic]

I have several question regarding my design:

- Are the analog and digital ground well positioned ?
- Is the way I traced +5V power line the right way to do ? Is it better to use the bottom layer ?
- Does the clock need to be on analog or digital ground ?

**Edit: new design of the PCB**

[image: new pcb]

Comment: Clock GND is connected to signal input ground (can this couple clock noise into the input source? Sure can...)  But this ground is "powered" from J2 pin 4 - all the way around the board in a circle.  Move X1 down and right slightly, and tie its ground to that much closer strip of J2p4.  The higher the frequency of X1, the more "finnicky" it will become.

Comment: Should I tie the ground of the clock only to the digital ground or also to the analog ground with a trace to digital ground? Should I just move the link between digital and analog ground next to the clock ?

Comment: By tying X1 ground to that little island on the left of J2, the "current loop area" (path that these X1 currents flow) is much reduced in size.  More importantly, it is kept away from the analog stuff.  You're attempting to isolate analog grounds from digital grounds, by connecting them with the little strip to the right of the ADC - so connecting X1 ground only to the island makes sense to keep these currents away.

Comment: The better way is to use an entire PCB layer as gnd plane. And only make cutouts where it has to be isolated such as analog and digital gnd. Having your gnd in the same layer as your signal - as it appears you do - cuts a lot of openings in the copper lowering its ground properties. You should use the rear plane for gnd plane. The blue trace you have will make a cutout but either make it short, re-route on top if possible or make a jumper.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I will connect the clock much closer to J2 and put the ground plane on the bottom side of the pcb.